# How to embed an @ parameter in curl

Tags: curl

What is the correct way to embed an email string in a curl POST command? Doesn't the `@` get confused?

```
curl -d "name=Ivan&email=idf@xxx.com&password=secret" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded" -X POST http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register
```

Comment: looks like it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@` is only special if it is the first character specified as an argument to `-d`.  Use `--data-raw` if you want to avoid any ambiguity about the `@` character.